# How to check if user isSignedIn in Liferay, outside portlet and theme context?

Tags: jsp, liferay

We try to add a feature to a Liferay site, so the signed in users get the ability to purge the current page [from the varnish cache](http://giantdorks.org/alain/exploring-methods-to-purge-varnish-cache/) with one simple click.

So we add add the button in the admin_navigation.vm "clear cache", protected with

```
#if ($themeDisplay.isSignedIn())
```

to pass the url to a purge_me.jsp?url=page-to-purge

We want to let only signed in users to use the purge function inside this JSP. We included the portal initialisation and try to check:

```
<%@ include file="/html/portal/init.jsp" %>

<c:if test="<%= themeDisplay.isSignedIn() %>">
```

But this doesn't work.
How to get this work in a simple JSP-only way? Without the need for own classes e.g.

Answer (score 2):

Have you done the following bit of code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="liferay-theme" %>
<liferay-theme:defineObjects />
```

This will then allow you to access the ThemeAdmin object as the variable themeAdmin.

Comment: I think, this is soon done by the include of /html/portal/init.jsp, which includes /html/common/init.jsp

Comment: Ah yes, of course! Which version of Liferay are you using? Are you therefore developing in EXT?

Comment: It's Liferay 5.2.3 CE, without EXT, just the Tomcat bundle (6.0.18)

Comment: So you're developing a portlet with the Plugins-SDK? If so then I would personally not bother with the "/html/common/init.jsp" include, and just add the imports that you require for that one portlet. There's no need to import loads of classes you won't ever need.

Comment: It isn't a portlet, just a simple JSP Page, to call a shell script. I don't know classes, that are needed to check logged in users. It should be just a quite simple way. But it seems that isn't practicable in Liferay.

Comment: That will be because in Liferay you don't really have "simple JSP pages", any code should be part of a portlet. This is also probably the reason it's not working, because the code isn't in a portlet. I think you may have to re-evaluate how you do this.

Answer (score 0):

use $is_signed_in velocity variable in place of $themeDisplay.isSignedIn(). You can do the following in admin_navigation.vm

```
#if($is_signed_in)

 then show button for "clear cache"
#else

...stuff....

#end
```

Comment: I believe he's after a JSP solution, rather than a theme solution.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<c:if test="${!themeDisplay.isSignedIn()}">
    <liferay-captcha:captcha url="${captchaResourceURL}"/>
</c:if>
```